# jQuery autocomplete works fine in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox

I have a jQuery autocomplete function on a text input field that works fine in Firefox but does not respond in Chrome. Here is the script for the field:

```
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "La Plagne",
        "Geneva"
    ];
    $("#locationinput1, #locationinput2").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {}
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me in Chrome. Do you have jQuery and jQuery UI in the `<head>` tag, both placed above the autocomplete script?

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>  

<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "La Plagne",
        "Geneva"
    ];
    $("#locationinput1, #locationinput2").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/6vg8k770/) - Working in Chrome

Comment: Yes both are in the head above the script. Don't know whether it could be something to do with the code of the input field itself, however I can't see why it would be.

Comment: <input id="locationinput1" type="text" name="origin" placeholder="From (Airport/Resort)"/>

Comment: Is the JSFiddle that I posted working for you in Chrome? [JSFiddle with updated input code](http://jsfiddle.net/IronFlare/6vg8k770/1/) (makes no difference)

Comment: And if you copy the JSFiddle code into your page, does it still not respond in Chrome, or is the problem solved?

Comment: No it still won't work. Have just tried the JSFiddle with the CSS to see if there was an issue there but nope, it still works fine in JSFiddle. Really puzzled by this

Comment: Try putting your autocomplete script in a `$(document).ready(function() {...});` function. It's just a guess, but I figure it's worth a shot.

Answer (score -1):

Your code works fine in Chrome. Could you please tell us which version of Chrome are you using? 
i am using Version 41.0.2272.118 m and code works fie for me. 
Also in console check if any javascript error is coming or not.
If it is coming then first solve that error.it needs to resolve all javascript errors. i am placing code which i have tried. you can click on "Run Code Snippet" to check how code works.

```js
$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        "La Plagne",
        "Geneva"
    ];
    $("#locationinput1, #locationinput2").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags,
        messages: {
            noResults: '',
            results: function () {}
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<input id="locationinput1" type="text" name="origin" placeholder="From (Airport/Resort)"/>
<input id="locationinput2" type="text" name="destination" placeholder="To (Airport/Resort)"/>
```

Comment: Ran the code in the console. Got the following error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function. Not sure on how to fix this.

Comment: don't run above code in Console. Run your application on chrome and check console for errors in application. there should not be any javascript errors